# PhotoSwipe, header and footer menu

Tags: jquery, html, swipe

i try to do a photoswipe gallery for mobile devices. and what i want to do is on click on the touchscreen open the header and footer toolbar, because they have buttons to share and to do go back to another page.

But i cant select the buttons,

When i click at the header and footer,  i can only swipe to the right and left.

Someone can help me pls?

HTML5 Code:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
        <a href="Revista.html" class="ui-btn-left" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-role="button" data-theme="a"></a>
        <h1>HOME</h1>
    </div>


<div data-role="content" id="f">

<ul id="Gallery" class="gallery">

        <li><a href="img/image001.jpg"></a></li>

    </ul>
</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
      <ul class="social-likes" id="s">
            <li class="facebook" title="Facebook">Likes</li>
            <li class="twitter" title="Twitter">Twitter</li>
            <li last-option id="nomecontacto"><a href="#" onclick="showForm()" title="Enviar Mensagem">Contacto<img src="img/mail-icon.png"/></a></li>
    </ul>
</div> 


</div><!--rolepage-->

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        (function(window, PhotoSwipe){

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

                var
                    options = {
                        preventHide: true,
                                    },
                    instance = PhotoSwipe.attach( window.document.querySelectorAll('#Gallery a'), options );

                    instance.show(0);

            }, false);


        }(window, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

    </script>
```